# How to write a test which fails since scheduledExecutorService.shutdown wasn't called?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm TDDing through a unit which has a `ScheduledExecutorService` as a collaborator.
This unit has a `start` method which basically starts the executor with the task and I now want to write the test which drives the `stop` method because I know that given that no one will call `ScheduledExecutorService.shutdown` the thread will hang (by default not a daemon thread).

I wanted to do this via `@Test(timeout = 5000L)` and building the unit with an actual executor-service (and not a deterministic one) but the problem I'm facing is that for some reason the test doesn't hang.
I think, not sure, this is related to Intellij/Junit mix calls `system.exit` and killing "my" jvm.

In a manual "test" I wrote with a `main` method I can verify that without calling the `shutdown` method the system is indeed stuck.

Any ideas on how to test this?

Thanks

**Update**
I've put together a small code sample which illustrates the problem:

```
public class SomethingTest {
@Test(timeout = 5000L)
public void shouldStopExecutorServiceWhenStopped2() throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Something cds = new Something(scheduler);
    cds.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000); //this is to be pretty sure that the scheduling started since I'm not certain the thread will deterministically block otherwise
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Something cds = new Something(scheduler);
    cds.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000); //this is to be pretty sure that the scheduling started since I'm not certain the thread will deterministically block otherwise
    cds.stop(); //comment this out to see that it hangs if shutdown isn't called
}
public static class Something {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    public Something(ScheduledExecutorService scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void start() {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("did something really important over time");
            }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void stop() {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
} }
```

Comment: Why don't you mock the scheduled executor service, and ask the mock if it has been called or not? I'm not sure I understand the description of your code. Why don't youpost the code itself, expect what you expect it to do and what it does instead?

Comment: @JBNizet I try to follow the "only mock your own" rule and so I wouldn't like to mock the executor. I'll post a simplified version of the code in a couple of minutes. Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet I've added a code sample. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't really understand what you want. You would like the JUnit runner to run forever, just like it does when starting Something from within a main method? What would you gain by having a test that hangs forever? You've proved by your main example that not calling stop() makes the JVM hang. And you also proved that the current stop() implementation makes it stop hanging, by calling shutdownNow(). So have your test mock a ScheduledExecutorService and verify that the stop() method indeed calls shutdownNow(), to detect potential regressions. Please clarify if I haven't understood.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't want the test to hang forever (hence the @Test(*timeout*-5000L). I would like the junit runner to wait until the timeout if a non daemon thread is running. What I'm trying to achieve in a more general way is how to solve this kind of problem next time I encounter it. I'd prefer not having to go through the "main" option next time if I don't have to.

Comment: The test will fail if the test thread, running the test method, takes more than 5 seconds. Not if some other non-deamon thread is still running. But I still don't understand why you want a unit test to fail. The usual goal for a unit test is to succeed.

Comment: @JBNizet when I TDD I want the test to fail so I know the error message will tell me something in the future and that there is actually a feature waiting to happen. If the test passes then there is no need to write it or the production code which follows.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the timeout, you should have a clear rule that you will test in your case.

For example, let the test run for some time (in your case 2 seconds), and then assert that it has really finished it's job, for example some assertion on isTerminated() or isShutDown() on your scheduler.

However, the way you are running the test, it will always end before 5 seconds as the testing thread will not wait for the scheduler to finish.

Another option is to put a while loop like this (could also be isShutDown() depending on what you are needing):

```
while (!scheduler.isTerminated()) sleep(2000);
```

This should bring your test to fail if it takes more than 5 seconds and you will be putting your testing thread to wait until the scheduler is really finished or the execution time of your scheduler exceeds the timeout you set.

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not expose the executor or methods of it I don't use just for testing

Comment: Well, that's fine, but you need to have a rule of what you're testing. Your approach of makeing a new TestRule is fine, but you should not only validate daemon threads, but be able to check exactly for the thread you are testing so you don't mess up with other stuff.

Comment: I thought about that but I'm not sure that's true since in my specific use-case the need I'm trying to answer is ending up with a "non-stuck" system which means 0 non-daemon threads

Answer (score 0):

What I think I'm going to do (don't have the time for it now) is to write a JUnit TestRule very similar to Timeout rule which checks if there are any non-daemon threads running before it finishes.
Essentially I'd like the test to fail if there are any non daemon threads running since I want to verify the system won't hang after this pseudo block `new unit();unit.start;unit.stop` and I know that the system won't hang if no daemon threads will be running after some time (the input timeout to make the test deterministic and give the jvm the option to actually close that thread).